'Incorrect syntax near 'StaffFirstname'.' when trying to insert data
I keep getting the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'StaffFirstname'.'

The code is shown here, I can't see what is causing the error. Can someone please advise me what I am doing wrong
Private Sub BtnInsertData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInsertData.Click

     If Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
             Con.Close()
         End If
         Con.Open()
         cmd = Con.CreateCommand()
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into Staff StaffFirstname='" + TxtStaffFirstName.Text + "',StaffLastName='" + TxtStaffLastName.Text + "',StaffAddress='" + TxtStaffAddress.Text + "',StaffCity='" + TxtStaffCity.Text + "',StaffState='" + TxtStaffState.Text + "' ,StaffPostCode='" + TxtStaffPostCode.Text + "',StaffPhoneNumber='" + TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text + "',StaffEmail='" + TxtStaffEmail.Text + "' where Staffid=" & i & ""
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

     Disp_Data()

     TxtStaffFirstName.Text = ""
     TxtStaffLastName.Text = ""
     TxtStaffAddress.Text = ""
     TxtStaffCity.Text = ""
     TxtStaffState.Text = ""
     TxtStaffPostCode.Text = ""
     TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text = ""
     TxtStaffEmail.Text = ""

     MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully")

End Sub


Have a look at the official document for INSERT - your syntax is totally off.. it should be INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (list-of-columns) VALUES (list-of-values)

Your method is called "insert", but do you want to add rows or update rows? Insert doesn't make sense with a WHERE. Or is the idea to add a row if it doesn't exist, and otherwise update?

Thanks folk's, I wanted to both Insert and Update and I just got a bit lost. The code below did fix the update error, however the actual sql table didn't update. I will have look more into it, and if I can't work it out, ill post another question. Thanks guys, I am a complete novice, and I am a very old toolmaker by trade and I love to learn coding, but as you can see, I am not very good at it. Kevin

One way to do it is: update ...  where <something>; if @@rowcount = 0 insert into table (...) values ...

Also you are using a global connection object, which is a bad idea. Create and open a connection when needed, dispose it with Using.

You use INSERT but use where. I think you meant to use an UPDATE statement instead since you're using a WHERE clause.
If Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then 
Con.Close() 
End If 

Con.Open() 
cmd = Con.CreateCommand() 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text 

' Use UPDATE instead of INSERT and ensure to set the correct syntax
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET StaffFirstname = @FirstName, StaffLastName = @LastName, StaffAddress = @Address, StaffCity = @City, StaffState = @State, StaffPostCode = @PostCode, StaffPhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber, StaffEmail = @Email WHERE Staffid = @StaffId"

' Use parameters to prevent SQL injection
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TxtStaffFirstName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TxtStaffLastName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TxtStaffAddress.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TxtStaffCity.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", TxtStaffState.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", TxtStaffPostCode.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TxtStaffEmail.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffId", i)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

Disp_Data() 

' Clear the text fields after the operation
TxtStaffFirstName.Text = "" 
TxtStaffLastName.Text = "" 
TxtStaffAddress.Text = "" 
TxtStaffCity.Text = "" 
TxtStaffState.Text = "" 
TxtStaffPostCode.Text = "" 
TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text = "" 
TxtStaffEmail.Text = "" 

MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully")
End Sub


AddWithValue should not be used

@BillTürstandswithUkraine Why should AddWithValue not be used? The url you added might go offline or be removed, so it would be better to put at least a minimal explanation in your comment.

@JonasMetzler comments are for immediate feedback and are expected to be removed at some point. Therefore posting a link is acceptable, because its intended that the poster reads it soon and hopefully updates their answer.

"comments are for immediate feedback and are expected to be removed at some point" feels like an extraordinary claim that has direct contradictory evidence (i.e. open any answer above whatever threshold you consider old and observe that there are indeed comments that haven't been removed). Do you have official guidance that supports this claim?

@testing-for-ya - I hear you, but that wasn't the claim; "comments could be removed" is a weaker assertion than "comments are expected to be removed".
